# Spring-data-neo4j-Neoclipse-Lucene corrupt index Exception

Tags: exception, lucene, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, corrupt

I have configured my application using Spring-data-neo4j, where I can successfully persist, create relationships, etc.

Once I persist the data and stop my application, I then want to visualize the graph that I've created in NEOCLIPSE.

I can successfully see the graph as well in NEOCLIPSE.

The only problem I am having is.. once I close the connection in Neoclipse, and then re-run my application to `listAllSavedEntities` on a web page, I get this error :

```
`SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/sample] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: unrecognized format -3 in file "_0.fnm"] with root cause
org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: unrecognized format -3 in file "_0.fnm"
    at org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInfos.read(FieldInfos.java:349)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInfos.<init>(FieldInfos.java:71)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getFieldInfos(IndexWriter.java:1197)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getCurrentFieldInfos(IndexWriter.java:1213)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:1149)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.getIndexWriter(LuceneDataSource.java:602)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.getIndexSearcher(LuceneDataSource.java:499)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:248)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.get(LuceneIndex.java:187)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.AbstractIndexingTypeRepresentationStrategy.findAllRelBacked(AbstractIndexingTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.AbstractIndexingTypeRepresentationStrategy.findAll(AbstractIndexingTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategies.findAll(TypeRepresentationStrategies.java:80)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.findAll(Neo4jTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.AbstractGraphRepository.findAll(AbstractGraphRepository.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:322)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.adaranet.controller.DeviceController.listAllDevices(DeviceController.java:60)
    at com.adaranet.controller.DeviceController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$3ee50553.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at com.adaranet.controller.DeviceController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$52cdcf0f.listAllDevices(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`
```

I simply closed the connection in `Neoclipse` and then tried to `list` out my persisted entities. Nothing more to that.

I am not sure what's wrong in here :( :(

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What neo4j kernel version does your neoclipse use and which one your application? Could it be that there is a version mismatch? Maybe neoclipse upgrades the data directories content to a newer version under the hood. That could be the cause for that *unrecognized format -3* error message in your application.

Comment: I see.. how am I supposed to check the `neoclipe's` kernel version? 
`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.M02</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>`

These are my neo4j config dependencies in my pom file.

This is what I found in my neoclipse.ini
`-startup plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
`

Comment: Having a look at the download packages at https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neoclipse/downloads neoclipse's latest stable version seems to be 1.8. Did you install that one? It seems that its version number corresponds with the neo4j version number. According to your dependencies you are using neo4j 1.6.M02 which is an older one.

Comment: If you are not sure which neoclipse version you have installed: open neoclipse, go to the menu item _About Neoclipse_, then _Installation Details_, then _Configuration_. In that list you should see something like: `Id: org.neo4j.neoclipse, Version: 1.8.0, Location: initial@reference:file:plugins/org.neo4j.neoclipse_1.8.0.jar` I'd suggest you to either update your applications dependency to neo4j version 1.8 or use the older neoclipse version 1.6 if you are not allowed for some reason to upgrade your applications dependency.

Comment: Thanks h3nrik.. I will look into it and will get back to you if the error still persists.. I appreciate your response.

Comment: Thanks h3nrik, it seems to be working :) I've updated both, Spring dependencies and neo4j's as well. Thanks once again.